# In a subset of a dataframe, how to change value if non-blank

Tags: r

I have certain columns in a dataframe **df[,17:165]** that I want to change to 1 (for later summation) if they are not NA.

I have:

```
    Classical     Rock      Pop   Opera  Jazz 
1       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>   <NA>
2       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>   Jazz
3       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>   Jazz
```

And I want:

```
        Classical   Rock    Pop   Opera  Jazz 
1       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>   <NA>
2       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>     1
3       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>     1
```

So that I can then sum rows 1:3 to get a total # of genres per row.

I don't know how to change just a subset of data within the dataframe.

Data

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, na.strings = '<NA>', colClasses = 'factor',
                 text = " Classical     Rock      Pop   Opera  Jazz 
                 1       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>   <NA>
                 2       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>   Jazz
                 3       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>   Jazz")
```

Comment: @RichardScriven If I'm not mistaken, the class of the data.frame could be a problem in this case. If you consider the way `<NA>` is printed, the data is likely stored as a factor, and in that case your suggestion may not work.

Comment: Right. Since `'1'` is probably not a level in any of hte columns, assigning a non-existent level causes an NA.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather not modify a subset of the original data.frame `df`, especially not if it contains data stored as factors. Therefore, to avoid possible conflicts with different classes in the original data.frame, I would suggest creating a new data.frame `df2` like this:

```
df2 <- df[,17:165]
df2[] <- as.numeric(!is.na(df2))
```

The data.frame `df2` will have suitable column names and it will contain only 0 and 1 as entries. This should be an ideal format to perform the desired sums and other statistics.

Usually it is preferable to avoid inserting `NA`s when it is not absolutely necessary to do so. But if you need to obtain an output as described in the OP, you might use

```
df2[df2==0] <- NA_character_
```

---

**Example:**

With the data `dd` provided in the edit of the OP, a subsetting is not necessary and we could directly use `dd` instead of creating a copy `df2`. However, to illustrate the principle, we could select a subset of `dd` by using only the columns 2 to 5:

```
df2 <- dd[,2:5]
df2[] <- as.numeric(!is.na(df2))
```

This generates the following data.frame `df2`:

```
  Rock Pop Opera Jazz
1    0   0     0    0
2    0   0     0    1
3    0   0     0    1
```

---

**Note**

If you are only interested in calculating the sum of genres per row in the subset and no further analysis is required, then it is not necessary to copy a subset of the original data.frame and to perform the manipulations described above.

In that case you could simply use:

```
genresPerRow <- rowSums(!is.na(dd[,2:5]))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, na.strings = '<NA>', colClasses = 'character',
                 stringsAsFactors = F,
                 text = " Classical     Rock      Pop   Opera  Jazz 
                 1       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>   <NA>
                 2       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>   Jazz
                 3       <NA>       <NA>     <NA> <NA>   Jazz")

dd[!is.na(dd)] <- 1

  Classical Rock  Pop Opera Jazz
1      <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>
2      <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    1
3      <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    1
```

If they are already factors then change the class (one way is to use `as.character`), so that it doesn't generate an `NA` for an invalid factor level. In the code above I just changed factor to character.